# Turning off reverse geocoding when opening "Maps" in iPhone through a URL with lat./long. parameter

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps

I am trying to figure out how to use the Google Maps URL format for sharing locations as latitude/longitude in an app that I am developing for iPhone.

Example: http://maps.google.com/maps?q=40.77407,-73.96675
This is a point in Central Park, New York. When using this on an iPhone, "Maps" will open and reverse geocoding will be done, resulting in an address on the nearby 5th Ave.
But for sharing a meeting point in Central Park, this is quite useless!

Is it possible to specify any parameter in the query string that will turn off reverse geocoding, so that the exact lat/long position is shown in the "Maps" app on iPhone?

(Compare with the result one will get when entering this url on a desktop, where the exact location will always be pointed out by a green arrow.)

Comment: Using reverse geocoding is done by you, so just dont do it. The question is not too clear to be honest...where are you getting those location coordinated?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the maps app is showing a pin at the correct location, but is adding its own "title" - what Magnus wants to do is, I think, add his own title to the pin, so a URL like

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=40.77407,-73.96675&title=MyPlace 

(that's won't work though, just trying to clarify the issue)

Comment: Clarification: My app has a button for generating a URL with the purpose of letting the user export the location (directly to the "Maps" app or by pasting the URL into an e-mail). The problem with the URL in my example is that **the red pin that shows up in "Maps" is not shown at the right location!** Instead it is shown at the location that is found after that "Maps" has applied reverse geocoding to it! Compare the result when accessing my example URL from a desktop browser and from an iPhone! The "title" is not an issue in my case. I just want the red pin to be placed at the right location!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer myself: Adding "loc:" immediately after "q=" will turn off the reverse geocoding.

Example: http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:40.77407,-73.96675

Comment: @Martin: It worked in the app for app versions up to v. 1.1. Then from v. 2.0 (released summer 2013) it suddenly stopped working. It still does not work in app version v. 2.2.0. Unfortunately, I have not found any workaround. I have reported this to Google. Let's hope that they fix it in a future versions. If you think that this is important, please indicate your support by marking the following bug report with a star: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5680

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a generic 'q', which according to specification is treated like a generic query

> This parameter is treated as if it had been typed into the query box by the user on the maps.google.com page. q=* is not supported.

you could try **ll** or **saddr**.

```
ll     The latitude and longitude points (in decimal format, comma separated, and in that order) for the map center point.
saddr  The latitude and longitude points from which a business search should be performed.
```

The maps url scheme is specified here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html

Comment: "ll" is used for positioning the map center, without showing any red pin. "saddr" does not really make any sense in this case. And, yes, I have read the documentation...